# JQuery AJAX: Form submits twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my form I'm using ajax to submit the form. When I click submit button it executes the method twice. Can someone guide me to find out the problem

```
$("form#dealForm").submit(function(event){

    //disable the default form submission
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(event.target);

    //grab all form data
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
            alert(returndata.message);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

html:

```
<form name="dealForm" id="dealForm" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>deals/update_deal/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: This error doesnt feel like it is in your code. There must be 2 forms with same id or name. Try other browsers, try ajax document ready thing. try different pc(mouse :) ) i cant see anyother reason that can cause this.

Comment: Sounds like you either have the code twice, or it's in a function that you call twice. There's no way that the code will run multiple times spontaneously.

Comment: @user2102266 Even if you have two forms with the same ID, jQuery will ignore the duplicates. An ID selector will always return just the first match.

Comment: Are you double clicking on the submit button? (that would cause it to submit twice) It's a good idea to disable the submit button until the ajax call is complete.

Comment: No.This shows alert twice.Can't understand the problem.I'm using bootstrap validator.Maybe this occurs because of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if it works, the form is hooked to "submit" twice:

```
$("form#dealForm").unbind('submit').submit( ...
```

This will unbind submit, then bind your action. Just a fix if the form is already bound to submit. It is one of many possibilities, likely due to calling your script twice or perhaps your validation plugin binding the submit event separately.

Note: This can potentially unhook your validation plugin, or any other scripts bound to submit.

If this does fix the problem for you, you should investigate *why* it is happening. Then fix that, and remove the `unbind` command. It may fix this problem, but it may also cause more problems later. (AKA: Only use this for debugging)

Comment: Strange but this solved the issue. But still can't understand where does the other submit fires

Comment: You can start looking next to your existing code. Just above the code you provided, put an `alert('Test')`. If the alert fires twice, that code is being triggered twice. Then just work backwards until it no longer fires twice. It could be that the function containing your submit hook is called twice, or maybe even the jquery initialization is called twice. There's a lot of possibilities! Just throw alerts everywhere! (Also read about `console.log()`, but know it will throw a script error in old IE versions, stopping the script)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be your problem, but here is something to check.

One thing that causes this sort of problem is if you have injected the html/js into the DOM, whether via ajax or whatever. For example, if you have a button on your page that injects some html form code + js into a div, and then displays it in a dialog for the user to complete -- that sort of thing.

When you click the submit button the first time, the js will process once and then stop (therefore, one ajax submission). However, the next time the user fills out the form and clicks submit, it will process/submit twice. Next time three. etc.  I've run into this a number of times. *Solution is to move the js `.click` or `.submit` event out of the injected code.*

As I said, probably not what you are experiencing, but worth knowing about.